# Find the sum of cubes of roots of a biquadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Given that $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of the equation $x^4-3x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$, find the value of $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$. Since, there are no 'zero' coefficients in the equation, it looks like a tough job for Newton's Sums. Is there some trick? Thanks

Comment: You can write the polynomial as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ and expand this. This should give you a link between powers of your four roots and the polynomial you have. Play around with them until you are left with the sum of the cubes.

Comment: It's not a biquadratic (ax^4+bx^2+c) but a plain quartic equation.

Comment: @Bernard: it's a bit old-fashioned but biquadratic is used as a synonym for quartic. Confusingly, it is also used (as you suggest) for a quartic with no odd powers, so I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

As $abcd\ne0,$

$$a^4-3a^3+a^2-2a+1=0\iff a^3-3a^2+a-2+\dfrac1a=0$$

$$\sum a^3=3\sum a^2-\sum a+2\sum1-\sum\dfrac1a$$

Now by Vieta's formula, $\sum a=3$ and $\sum ab=1,\sum abc=2,abcd=1$

$\implies\sum a^2=(\sum a)^2-2\sum ab=\cdots$

Finally, $\sum\dfrac1a=\dfrac{\sum abc}{abcd}=\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: rather than a trick, there's a theorem, due to Newton: it says that a symmetric (polynomial) function $q(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of the roots of a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ is a polynomial function of the coefficients of $p$. See the wikipedia pages on [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^4-3x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$

$\sum{\alpha}^{3}$= the coeff. of $x^{-3}$ in $\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$